# should i lift external weights when i can't able to lift my body weight

Tags: strength, muscle-mass, pull-ups, weights

I am **27 , 6.1 , 70kg** , physically weak person , From last 5 months i am doing workout 4 days in a week , but did't found any progress as i am not taking good amount of protein....

I can't do single pull ups on my own & I was doing Barbell Press with weights yesterday.... Someone said "**When you can't lift your own body weight, than don't do other weights related workouts.... initially you need to get core strength , than start lifting weights**" He suggested to do only **push ups, squats , cardio** and than get some basic strength & than start do weight training excercises to get muscles.....

So As he suggested may i concentrate on getting **core strength** first or may i continue doing weight & other machine workouts to get **muscles**....

I want to get both strength &  muscles,....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's truth that core strength is very important. Strong core helps prevent injuries. You mentioned barbell press, I not sure it benchpress or overhead press. Overhead press is very demanding on core strength if executed in standing position. I don't say that you should completely avoid weights, but if you can't do GHD extension, there is no point to do deadlifts. If you can't do pushup there is no point do benchpress, because pushups are easier and safer. If you can't do chin up, there is no point do biceps curls, because for you better will be first focus on chin ups. 
But you started to do something, thats is very good, and results will comes with time.

Comment: I was doing `seated inclined barbell bench press` & i can do 8 * 3 pushups....

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Standing overhead press is not demanding on of core strength, standing overhead press *develops* core strength. Deadlifts are an excellent exercise even if you've never looked at a GHD machine. Bench press is very useful for people who can't do pushups, as it allows lighter weights to be used an in a pushup. Similarly with chin-ups, people who can't do even one rep will need an easier variation first.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but it absolutely makes no sense to think that there is only one way to achieve your goal in terms of fitness. You may be not able no do pull ups(that also applied to me when I was a beginner) but you can work your way through it using external weight rows, pulls etc. This pull up example also works for push ups and squats.

For core strength, there are tons of external or bodyweight exercises you can do to get stronger.

Please don't let people who aren't experts (they can be looking good, this doesn't mean they know what's good for you) demotivate you from doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is progressive weight training for some they need to progress beyond push ups or sit ups. For others they can't lift their own body weight so machines or free weights help them get there. I've seen many smaller people that could barely lift a bare bar, but that is ok if that is where they need to start. The alternative is to never start because you can't complete a single pushup, chin up etc.

I'd suggest starting with "core" exercises, bench press, deadlift, squat. With whatever weight you can handle safely for 10 reps. I'd also throw in some light back extensions and either sit ups if you can do them unadded or find a crunch machine. The core exercises give you the most bang for your buck in terms of muscles used and their ability to stimulate growth hormone production. The core exercises make sure that your stabilizing muscles are kept in good working order (and balanced between each other) to protect your back.

Don't be afraid to find a knowledgeable buddy or a trainer to help out if you don't know what you are doing. The worse way to workout is to spend 6mths off training because you hurt yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Negative pull ups or scapular pull ups will get you the fastest results and anyone can do them, even kids and obese people.

To get better at pull ups do pull ups.

To get better at moving around weights you need to do just that.

Don't  listen to people that don't  even know the core is the entirity of the torso from the glutes to the neck including everything inbetween.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(anatomy)

Or people that use the term "stabilizing muscles" 
All muscles pull joints and none stabilizes that's  the only thing they do... There's  no such thing as "stabilizers" or "stabilizing muscles"